# filter number from Phone book by replacing all special characters in Android?

Tags: android

I am working with the contacts fetched from my default Phone book in Android. When I fetch contacts from phone book, sometime I am getting "-", "(" etc characters.

If the characters are known then I can easily remove them with **relpace()** method but my client complaint that some times they got to see % like symbols too in the number fetch from phone book.

Please suggest me, how can I filter the numbers fetch from Phone book, so that I can have **only and only digits** in my text field and no else characters.

Currently I am using `string.replace("-","");` for removing '-' from the contact number.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#stripSeparators(java.lang.String)) (available in API 1+).

---

*Edited*

Or you can use [regular expression‌](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)​:

```
filterNum = filterNum.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
```

— which will remove all characters which are not in range `0...9`. I think it would be easier. Here's [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: This method will work for '-' character only.... but when we add contact in phone book then we are given with so many special characters like *,#,space, parenthesis etc....they were creating problem for me. Now I have user the core Java concepts & solved my problem. thanks for answering.  & Yes it was useful knowledge for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.replaceAll("[^0-9\\+]", "");
```

Here I am assuming that there will be no `'+'` within the number (only in front). If there is any chance of that then that will have to be checked separately

Comment: previous one will allow comma also

Answer (score 1):

I have used the core Java concepts get ride of this problem.

```
/**
     * removeSpecialCharacters
     * @param number
     * @return
     */
    private String removeSpecialCharacters(String number) {
        String filterNum = number;
        if(filterNum.contains("-")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("-", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("(")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("(", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains(")")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace(")", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains(".")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace(".", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("/")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("/", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains(",")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace(",", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("#")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("#", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("*")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("*", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("+")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("+", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("N")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("N", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains(";")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace(";", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("%")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("%", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains(" ")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace(" ", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("@")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("@", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("$")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("$", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("^")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("^", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("&")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("&", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("_")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("_", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("=")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("=", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("~")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace("~", "");
        }
        if(filterNum.contains("`")){
            filterNum = filterNum.replace(";", "");
        }

        return filterNum;
    }
```

Comment: You can use [regular expression](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html): `filterNum = filterNum.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");` — which will remove all characters which are not in range `0...9`. I think it would be easier. Here's [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).